# How to compare two expressions with maxima?

Tags: compare, maxima

I have two complicated mathematical expressions. How can I compare them, to find if they express the same using Maxima?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`is(equal(e1, e2))`. Note that "=" is identity (i.e. same expression), while "equal" is equivalence. E.g. `is(equal(x*(x + 1), x^2 + x))` => `true` while `is(x*(x + 1) = x^2 + x)` => `false`. Note also that `is(equal(e1, e2))` actually computes `ratsimp(e1 - e2)` and looks to see if the result is 0. Maxima cannot reduce all equivalent expressions to 0 so there are cases in which it will incorrectly return `false`.